# Getting the value present in table 1 to table2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to develop a report having two tables with one single data set.each table is filtered with the user giving a date parameter. is there any way that I can get the value present in a text of table1 into the table 2.

Comment: "a report having two tables with one single data set" - does this mean that you have two table objects in your report, both of which are reporting off the same dataset? Or that there are two database tables queried in your dataset? Can you supply some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a report with two table objects in it, both of which point at the same dataset, then all of the data in either table will be available in the other table - the only reason that one value would be available in one table but not the other is if the tables have different filter conditions. Therefore, you may need to amend the filter conditions.

Comment: Mark, is there any way that i can assign the textvalue into an internal variable . The custom report is ment for an online mscrm application where we wont be able to have access to the database. we are using the fetch query for creating the dataset. any kind of data operations should be done on dataset itself only.

Comment: @Jaipal: Please can you answer the questions in my comment on your question? Your comments on this answer make it sound as though you have a completely different problem to that described in your original question.

Comment: let me put forth answer to your question in this way.

Comment: let me put forth answer to your question in this way.The Report is having two tables with single data set as a data source.The two tables will display the records based on the table filters that i provide. now i need to pull out a calculated field in one of the text boxes from report1 and use it in report 2.

Comment: "i need to pull out a calculated field in one of the text boxes from report1 and use it in report 2" - assuming you mean from **table1** into **table2**, why not just copy and paste the calculation formula from table1 into the equivalent place in table2?

Comment: even though the expression is same for both the tables , its the filter expression  on both the tables that makes the difference. Difference. The calculated cell in table1 is based on the filter given for table1 and same is for table2.

Comment: So amend the filter conditions - as I originally suggested.